# How can GetKeyState be modified for only one process from a different process?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have 2 processes:

- UI process
- Client process

I am trying to have the client process send a message to the UI process's Thread/Windows in a way that it will affect it's GetKeyState's result. I want only to affect the UI process's GetKeyState and not any other process.

SendInput will affect all processes including this one, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Posting WM_KEYDOWN+WM_KEYUP does get handled but doesn't affect GetKeyState

Is there a way (by message or a hook) I can make the client affect the UI without changing the UI's code?

This is the part in the windowProc I print the value of GetKeyState of `A`:

```cpp
char* GetTextualKeyState(int nVirtKey) {
    short keyState = GetKeyState(nVirtKey);

    short KEY_DOWN_MASK = 0b1000000000000000;
    short TOGGLED_MASK= 0b1;

    const int TEXTUAL_KEY_STATE_LEN = 128;
    char* textualKeyState = (char *)calloc(TEXTUAL_KEY_STATE_LEN, sizeof(char));

    if (keyState & KEY_DOWN_MASK) {
        char down[] = "Down, ";
        strcpy_s(textualKeyState, TEXTUAL_KEY_STATE_LEN, down);
    }
    else {
        char up[] = "Up, ";
        strcpy_s(textualKeyState, TEXTUAL_KEY_STATE_LEN, up);
    }

    if (keyState & TOGGLED_MASK) {
        char toggled[] = "Toggled";
        strcat_s(textualKeyState, TEXTUAL_KEY_STATE_LEN, toggled);
    }

    return textualKeyState;


BOOL PaintKeyStateOfA(HDC hdc) {
    const int VK_A = 0x41;

    char* state = GetTextualKeyState(VK_A);

    const int CONTENT_LEN = 128;
    char labelContent[CONTENT_LEN] = "A KeyState: ";
    strcat_s(labelContent, CONTENT_LEN, state);

    return TextOutA(hdc, 10, 50, labelContent, strlen(labelContent));
```

Another thing I tried to do in order to debug GetKeyState was to add an infinite loop inside the GetMessage loop (right after DispatchMessage) that logs the output of GetKeyState and saw that:

1. As expected the window froze
2. The printed value was not affected

What am I missing here?

Comment: You automate a UI by using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: SendInput doesn't affect all processes. I mean, when you type, only one process sees that input.

Comment: [Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki) seems what you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: when I type anywhere, the keystate changes, regardless if the window is active or not.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: Detours might work for me

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Doesn't sound like what you are describing here is going to be the right solution to any problem.

Comment: I'm trying to do an automation for a process not written by me, in a non-disruptive way for the user. i.e. the process will run in the background, actions will be performed, like typing and mouse clicks, but the user can still work on other processes

Comment: Isn't that what UI Automation is for?

Comment: I don't know UI Automation. Is it non disruptive? Can it simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks in all windows apps? Without interfering with the user's experience?

Comment: I posted a link to reference documentation in my first comment. So no, it does not allow you to simulate keyboard or mouse input. It automates the UI at a much higher level. It is non-invasive, and will not interfere with a user supplying keyboard or mouse input.

Comment: @IInspectable: I thank you for that, but as far as I could understand, it enable automation in all types of UIs. Let's say I want to send text to a window (type or fill a textbox). In WPF it will work since there are textboxes with a value property I can fill, but in other native UIs such as Java Swing for example where there is one window, and the controls are not exposed in the element tree, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: You seem to be lacking a fundamental understanding of Windows' native windowing system. The fact that WPF's source-level representation of its UI widgets provides a particular property does not imply that that property were accessible to an external application. In fact, you cannot 'automate' a WPF UI by sending window messages *at all*. UI Automation is your only option. If UI Automation doesn't work then nothing will (unless the vendor provides a custom automation protocol).